# Why can't QNAP and its containers be pinged by name, while others can?

Tags: docker, dns, docker-container, mdns, qnap

In my local network, I have set up static DNS on the MikroTik router. All devices and PCs in the network are pingable by name, and on those where it's supported, you can also access them by name in the browser. I added a QNAP NAS to my network. If the version matters, it's a TS-253B. QTS 5.1.5. I installed Container Station (3.0.5) and tried to launch a container, let it be phpMyAdmin. For its network, I chose a bridge in Container Station interface. The container was installed, the bridge came up, and it is visible in the virtual switch. On the MikroTik and QNAP, as well as the container, are also visible and have obtained IP addresses, to which static names are attached, such as "qnap.local" and "container.local". However, they can only be pinged by IP address, not by name. If I ping them by name from the MikroTik itself, they respond with two packets, meaning two packets pass through, and two are lost (timeout). If I SSH into the QNAP, then the entire network is pingable by name from it, including itself and the container.

If you look at QTS on the Network and Virtual Switch tab, the switch has the same address as the network adapter. I don't know if this is normal, but I couldn't change it.

Even if I delete all containers and virtual switches so that only one network adapter remains, QNAP still cannot be pinged by name even from the Microtik.

So the problem is not with Docker and containers, but most likely with the settings of QNAP.

Within a few days I was able to find out that on any QNAP the Bonjour service is enabled by default for working with mDNS names. Indeed, if you ping or go to the browser using the name configured in the mDNS service, then everything works. But this is inconvenient and it is not clear what to do with distribution via DHCP and centralized configuration of names, especially since it is not clear where names for containers are configured. I wouldn’t want to disable mDNS (Bonjour) either. It would be nice if both services worked simultaneously.